# Azure Function App is not working after publishing but works in Local through VS2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I've Created an [Function App with HttpTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio) as per Microsoft documentation

I've tested it locally and works fine. Later, published it to Azure. I see it doesn't work now. While Function App creation, i see a small error/warning, not sure what it is...Placed that screenshot attached
Am new to Azure, please help me

[image: Not sure if its Function App Creation issue]

Comment: Please elaborate what "not working" means

Comment: I believe that communities can help you if you can provide more details about the error. ;-)

Comment: On accessing the url, i'm not getting the result. Please check the Microsoft documentaion link, i've given in problem statement
[Azure Url] (https://functionhello.azurewebsites.net?name=abc)

Comment: Click the Functions > "your HttpTrigger ", Try to run and then check the logs and output information.

Comment: @Wayneyang-MSFT -  I'm new to azure, could you please guide me on what's these communities and how to reach them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please click `Get function URL` button to see which URL you should be using. The format should be something like

```
https://functionhello.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpFunction?name=abc
```

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail. I added /api/myfunction to azure Url, it works now

New url:  https://functionhello.azurewebsites.net/api/myFunction?name=abc